# Adding newuser in docker container with sudo privileges

Tags: bash, docker

Im trying to build a docker file and one of the reqt is to create a user with sudo permissions.

Here is the bash script

```
# quietly add a user without password
adduser --quiet --disabled-password --shell /bin/bash --home /home/newuser --gecos "testuser" newuser
# set password
echo "testuser:testuser" | sudo chpasswd
```

and the docker compose file.

```
FROM ros
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
ADD run.sh /usr/local/bin/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run.sh
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run.sh"]
```

When I run this build I get the following error.

```
chpasswd: (user testuser) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user testuser) password not changed
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you're misinterpreting the requirements.  Creating an user with *sudo* permissions is different from creating an user with the `sudo` command.

Depending on the distribution, an user may run `sudo` if it belongs to the ***wheel*** or ***sudo*** group (the latter is the case with Ubuntu, which is the base image used by **ros**).

I strongly suggest that you use the `useradd` command instead of `adduser`.  The latter is different in Debian & RedHat based distributions, unlike the former which is the same across Linux distributions and even *BSD if you don't use the long options.  Also, the former lets you specify the supplementary groups in the command line (`-G` option).

`useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G sudo newuser`

If you use the `-p` option you could also supply the password in *encrypted form* (the term in the manpage should be *hashed form*) without the need to use `chpasswd` later.  Use the output of `mkpasswd -m sha-512`.  (The `mkpasswd` command is present in the **whois** package).  If you're going to use `chpass`, use the `-e` option to supply the password in *encrypted form*.  Never use plaintext.